# how to use controll at run time after getting data from server

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to make survey app in which i get question from server problem is that i want to place the controll as question like if i have question like having list then i want dropdown list if question type is yes or no then we can use toggle button like this and other type is to use slider so is there way to dynamically place and create controlls at run time aftaer getting question and then add to view

So how to add controls to view at run time in ipad application so that according to question type we have controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add runtime controls,
Just when you are getting your response from the service after that according to the response create controls programmatically,

OR

If you are aware about the response means only 4 kinds or 5 kinds of response will come than take all controls in .Xib file and use them after getting the server response.

Simply add the control whatever you have needed and hide all other.

This is a simple way, Hope you got my point:)

Comment: Second is fine i know that i have to use slider toggle or swith button and then drop down then how can add them in xib

Comment: Create iboutlet in your .h file and Simply drag and drop your controls in .xib file and connect the outlets Dear!! and do appropriate code for add and remove controls.

Comment: how will use them if i give firt dropdown and in response there is toggle then how will i hide and place

Comment: for Add:-[self.view addsubview:"your control"]; and for remove ["your control" removefromsuperview];or ["your control" set hidden:YES];

Comment: i know how to add but let say i have three question ok one for dropdwon one for toggle and one for slider if i place 1 slider and response is toggle then how will replace it i think you are saying that may place all the controlls on overlap

Comment: Just Remove that, Hide that controls.

Comment: ok one more thing to ask if user selcts all the dropdwon boxes then it mean i have to add 3 tableViews  3 toggle button 3 sliders for 3 questions and hide them according to the type